Screw on roof tiles coming loose
I checked on the roof and found out all the screw on the top is coming off by few mm. I also found that theres a moisture on the middle beam inside the roof. I think that was due to that water sipping inside through screw hole. I was wondering if that screw is supposed to have gap between roof tile and screw head for expansion and contraction or it need to be tighten. I have picture to give an ideas.



I don't think I have ever seen screws used for roofing... Where is this?

There is round headed nail on the top middle. This might not be screw. I am not sure.

For nails coming/popping out it is better to move them over and make a new hole or use screws.  You then need to seal the old holes with roof tar/sealer.
